# getting error : Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLENAME" syntax error (code 1) compiling a SELECT query

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm getting the following error while compiling a SELECT query:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "group": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT group_id, logo FROM group WHERE group_name = 'Empty Group'
```

The query is created as:

```
c = database.query(TABLE_GROUP, new String[]{KEY_GROUPID, KEY_LOGO}, KEY_GROUPNAME + " = '" + description + "'", null, null, null, null);
```

with:

```
TABLE_GROUP = "group";
KEY_LOGO = "logo";
KEY_GROUPID = "group_id";
```

and the creation script for the table:

```
create table group 
(group_id integer primary key autoincrement, 
group_name text not null, 
logo string);
```

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: make sure you have created group table   in db

Comment: make sure 'group' is not a keyword. change table's name to something else then check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

group is a `SQLITE` keyword and, as every reserved words, it can't use it as table/column name. To fix chose another name for your column. You can find a list of the `SQLITE` reserved keywords [here](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Comment: You're completely right. I completely forgot that "group by" can be used in SQL. I needed someone to remember me! Thank you!